# Action undefined when using rsaa middleware in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt, redux-thunk

I used [this guide](https://medium.com/@viewflow/full-stack-django-quick-start-with-jwt-auth-and-react-redux-part-iii-873584a65119) to set up authentication with my api using `jwt` token authentication from `Django` rest framework.  I can log in just fine.  But currently I set up another endpoint to get the user info of the currently authorized user (determined by the token they send with the request).

It's dispatched like so (done some time after the user logs in)

```
fetchUser: () => dispatch(loadUser()),
```

My **action** to load username:

```
import { RSAA } from 'redux-api-middleware';
import withAuth from '../reducers'

export const USER_REQUEST = '@@user/USER_REQUEST';
export const USER_SUCCESS = '@@user/USER_SUCCESS';
export const USER_FAILURE = '@@user/USER_FAILURE';

export const loadUser = () => ({
    [RSAA]: {
        endpoint: '/api/user/info/',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: withAuth({}),
        types: [
            USER_REQUEST, USER_SUCCESS, USER_FAILURE
        ]
    }
});
```

**Reducer**:

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'
import * as user from '../actions/user'

const initialState = {};

export default (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case user.USER_SUCCESS:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export const userInfo = (state) => state.user;
```

**Reducer `index.js`**:

```
export function withAuth(headers={}) {
    return (state) => ({
        ...headers,
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken(state)}`
    })
}

export const userInfo = state => fromUser.userInfo(state.user);
```

But when I try to get the user info of the logged in user, I get an error..

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

[image: extended error information]

Why is the action type undefined?

Note: I tagged this with thunk because my project does use thunk, but not for this bit of redux.

Edit:  My [`middleware.js`](https://bitbucket.org/cclloyd9785/opensrd-fullstack/src/master/src/frontend/src/middleware.js) and my [`store.js`](https://bitbucket.org/cclloyd9785/opensrd-fullstack/src/master/src/frontend/src/store.js).

Comment: where is your middleware code

Comment: @GauravPaliwal Added them at the end of my post.

Comment: are you using the wrong `loadUsername` function? why do you have two of them? (one in the reducer)

Comment: @azium I am certain I am using the right one.  the dispatch from `onSubmit` is calling the one in my actions file.  The other one is a state access method used in my `matchStateToProps`.  I just didn't bother giving them different names.  I also commited all my current changes if you want to look at the full code.  I'll add the relevant files as links in my post for easy access.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in `store.js` that `thunk` is applied before the `redux-api-middleware` middleware.

Just move it to after like this:

```
const store = createStore(
        reducer, {},
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(apiMiddleware, thunk, routerMiddleware(history)),
            window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f,
        ),
    );
```